# Simple Form update without DB persistence

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 3 dummy app (just learning MVC coming from WebForms).

And I'm pretty confused about how to update a form without actually having some DB stuff in between. I just have a form with a textbox and after I press the button I want to see the string in uppercase. But my nothing happens.

**The controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ToUppercaseModel model = new ToUppercaseModel { TheString = "testing" };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ToUppercaseModel model)
    {
        model.TheString = model.TheString.ToUpper();

        return View(model);
    }
```

**The model:**

```
public class ToUppercaseModel
{
    [Display(Name = "My String")]
    public string TheString { get; set; }
}
```

**And the view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TheString)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TheString)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Convert" />
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

This is a simple as it gets I think. Now obviously the `return View(model);` in the 2nd Index method is not working. I saw some stuff about `RedirectToAction()` and storing the data in `TempData`. Most example just submit some id, but since I don't have db that does not work.

If I do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
```

I get a

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Error Message. This should be simple, no? I think I understand the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) concept, but don't see how to apply it for something simple as this.

Thanks for some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MVC renders a view it will use the attempted value of a field rather than the model's value if it exists (eg in a datefield I put "Tuesday", this won't model bind but you'll want to show the user the field with their input and highlighted as invalid), you're changing the model's value but not the attempted value.

The attempted value is held in the modelstate dictionary:

`ModelState["KeyToMyValue"].Value.Value.AttemptedValue`

Accessing and changing these values can be tricky unless you want a load of magic strings in your code, and as validation happens on modelbinding your changed value won't be validated.

My recommendation in these circumstances is to call `ModelState.Clear()`, this will remove all validation and attempted values, then change your model directly. Finally you want to get your validation on the model by using `TryValidateModel(yourModel)`.

Be aware that this method is probably the easiest non-hacky method of doing this but will remove attempted values that could not bind from the returned view.

Comment: Thanks. This  works. But basically the proper way would be to use RedirectToAction? Or not?

Comment: @Remy No, the proper for returning a posted, invalid form is to return the form. The PRG pattern is for returning a view after a successful form post (to stop people refreshing and resubmitting a successful form). You would generally have your RedirectToAction within a block testing for ModelState.IsValid after your TryValidateModel

Answer (score 1):

You have to call 1 method from the 2 method, but you have to change it

public ActionResult Index(ToUppercaseModel model)

and send to 1 method your model.

```
public ActionResult Index(ToUppercaseModel? model)
    {
        if (model == null)    
        ToUppercaseModel model = new ToUppercaseModel { TheString = "testing" };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: But that would make my 1st method look exactly like my 2nd method. Both have "public ActionResult Index(ToUppercaseModel model)"

Comment: Yeah. But it works. In fact they are different. One of them is a POST method. Also the code is different. I guess you cannot update your page using POST method. It returns your model as it is with data you have inserted only.

Comment: Actually, having 2 methods with exactly the same signature does not compile. Maybe I don't see something? Could you maybe update your example?

Comment: Sorry, change 1 method signature   public ActionResult Index(ToUppercaseModel model) into public ActionResult Index(ToUppercaseModel? model) or  ActionResult Index(Nullable<ToUppercaseModel> model)

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes the difference :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution, it works, but not sure if this is the way it should be?
Basically I just put my model into the TempData and call the normal Index method again.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ToUppercaseModel model = null;

        if (TempData["FeaturedProduct"] == null)
        {
            model = new ToUppercaseModel { TheString = "testing" };
        }
        else
        {
            model = (ToUppercaseModel)TempData["FeaturedProduct"];
        }
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ToUppercaseModel model)
    {
        model.TheString = model.TheString.ToUpper();

        TempData["FeaturedProduct"] = model;

        //return View(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Well... It could be like this... But I prefer my solution! ;) With my solution you got less coding!!! :)

Comment: Actually, I went with Chao's solution. Yours is fine too, I posted mine before your clarification and i gave you an Up Vote.